# Solve a quadratic form equation on a field with characteristic 2

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, quadratic-forms

How can you find all of the solutions of a quadratic equation $x^t A x = g$ over a field with a characteristic 2 in a polynomial numbers of operations (specifically $GF(2)$)?

In a field with a characteristic $\not= 2$ this can be solved by representing the quadratic form in a diagonal matrix over some base, and solving $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... = g$, but in a field with characteristic a quadratic form doesn't always have a diagonal matrix. How can you solve it in that case in a polynomial numbers of operations?

Comment: If your field is finite (which is the case of $GF(2)$), then you have a finite number of elements and a finite number of $n$-uples... So testing all of them is a way to achieve your goal.

Comment: It is a way, but it's very inefficent when dealing with big quadratics. Is there a faster way?

Comment: This is for sure. Maybe you should then precise in your question that you'd like the answer to describe required number of operations. I at least added the algorithms tag to your question.

Comment: I edited it, is it good now?

Comment: That's great thanks!